# Reload complete configuration from within vim

Tags: vimrc

Every now and then I update my ViM configuration, and I would like to have a way to reload everything.

I know that I could use

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

and I could run it similarly for all the modified files. But as vim loads e.g. the system-wide configuration and the content of the `~/.vim/` directory, it can be some effort to source all those files again.

**Is there a way to reload the whole set in one command?**

Ideally, it should stop sourcing the previous configuration file and resource all anew.

Comment: [Vimdoc 3.c](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#c) says: `Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists is used, the others are ignored.` "$HOME/.vimrc" is searched first. And then 4:`:runtime! plugin/**/*.vim` The result is that all directories in the 'runtimepath' option will be searched for the "plugin" sub-directory and all files ending in ".vim" will be sourced (in alphabetical order per directory), also in subdirectories. But if you using one of plugin-manager it  reload your plugins with `source` command I believe.

Answer (score 2):

3 options

1. Restart vim (using sessions, e.g., with tpope’s obsession plugin, this isn’t really too bad)
2. Source only your vimrc (if it changed)—you have this
3. Load files with `runtime` (I use `Runtime` from tpope’s scriptease plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Are your "modified files" not sourced by default of from within .vimrc?

If you add the

```
source /path/to/additional/config/file
```

directive to your .vimrc, that would do the whole thing in one go.

You can then even

```
nnoremap <leader>r :source ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

to have `<leader>r` (default  `<leader>` is `/`, I believe) reload your config with two keystrokes.

Two things additionally:

1. Thank you for asking the question! This prompted me to - *at last* - also put this into my own config. Very convenient!
2. I set `<leader>` to be the Space key (`let mapleader = " "`) and am *very* happy with that.